# Different ways to find a the number of nodes at a given level

Tags: python

I have a home work problem that asks me to find the number of nodes at a given level (argument of the function). Now I know there are tons of similar questions that have been asked before. I tried the answers but it didn't work for me. So I need input from the community to tell me what I'm doing wrong and other ways I can do this problem. This is what I have:

```
def nodes_at_level(tnode, desired_level):
    """
    Purpose:
        Return the number of nodes in the tree at the given level.
    Pre-conditions:
        :param treenode: a treenode
        :param level: a non-negative integer
    Return:
        The number of nodes at the given level.
   """
   if tnode is None:
      return
   elif desired_level == 0:
       return
   else:
       return nodes_at_level(tn.get_left(tnode), desired_level - 1) \
      + nodes_at_level(tn.get_right(tnode), desired_level - 1)
```

tn is just the tree node adt in implemented as a dictionary.

Comment: How are you storing the tree?

Comment: What do you mean? Like how the tree looks? Or are you asking about the implementation of the tree?

Comment: Both. How are you storing the tree?Is it binary tree or m- ary

Comment: Oh, its going to be a binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def nodes_at_level(tnode, desired_level):
    """
    Purpose:
        Return the number of nodes in the tree at the given level.
    Pre-conditions:
        :param treenode: a treenode
        :param level: a non-negative integer
    Return:
        The number of nodes at the given level.
   """
   if tnode is None:
      return 0
   elif desired_level == 0:
       return 1
   else:
       return nodes_at_level(tn.get_left(tnode), desired_level - 1) \
      + nodes_at_level(tn.get_right(tnode), desired_level - 1)
```

Comment: Oh, silly mistake. Didn't notice I didn't put a return for those cases. Is there another way of solving this problem though?

Comment: @AaronJaredBagay There are many other ways to do this. Using the idea of on level traversal of http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/level-order-tree-traversal is one of them. Another one is adding a depth property to each node. But your algorithm would be the simplest.